# Raspberry PI 4 - Cameras - failed to import fd 20

Tags: raspberry-pi, camera, raspberry-pi4

I have a problem with the cameras for the RPI. I have two V2 cameras connected to the RPI with a Multi Camera Board V2 module. When trying to preview or test the cameras, an error pops up:
failed to import fd 20

What can I do to fix this?

I'll also add that shooting via libcamera-still throws up that it can't see the camera, but when I add -n to not preview, the picture takes normally.

I searched google for solutions, but unfortunately I did not find anything that solved my problem. I added various commands to cmdline.txt, nothing improved.